# when I want to express that a job is easy to finish, should I use "simple" or "easy"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56512128/10731613) is talking about an image processing problem.

in this context, I want to express that the job is easy to finish with OpenCV.

1. it is very easy to do the job with OpenCV.
2. it is very simple to do the job with OpenCV.

which one should I say? or some other better expression?

Comment: If you *want* to say that it's ***easy*** *to finish*, why would you bother trying to come up with a different word? Just use the word that means *exactly* the same thing—the word itself.

Comment: Why do you feel one is somehow "better" than the other?  Please add more detail to your question to explain what research you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine, and mean roughly the same.

"Simple" suggests the job is not complex: You can do it in one process.

"Easy" suggests the job is not difficult.

Consider "straightforward" as an alternative.